# Three.js Error: no keyframes in track named [objectname].position

Tags: three.js

Exporting from Blender [this animation](https://sport.xbe.at/jsonPlayer/index.html) in three.js format i get this error: "Error: no keyframes in track named Mesh.position". The Blender file have all the orphan data purged. I noticed that at bottom of exported [json file](https://sport.xbe.at/jsonPlayer/Player_animated_separated.json) there's a section with a empty animations:

```
"animations":[{
    "tracks":[{
        "type":"vector3",
        "name":"Mesh.position",
        "keys":[]
    },{
        "type":"vector3",
        "name":"Mesh.scale",
        "keys":[]
    },{
        "type":"quaternion",
        "name":"Mesh.quaternion",
        "keys":[]
    }],
    "name":"default",
    "fps":30
}]
```

If removed all worked correctly: it's a bug in the exporter or some parameters that i missing in the [Blender file](https://sport.xbe.at/jsonPlayer/Player_animated_separated.blend)?

Parameters used for exportation:

[image]